# Running SpringBoot JUnit tests requiring a docker environment in GitLab CI with Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci, testcontainers

I'm trying to get my pipeline up and running, where I run unit tests from my Spring boot application. I'm using gradle so I can locally run the tests just fine with `gradle test --rerun-tasks`. However, once I try this with GitLab CI I run into a problem.

In my tests I make use of Testcontainers, most importantly a MySQL container, which requires a docker environment. If I use a docker image for my testing stage there is no Java present, so gradle can't run. If I use a Java image, I get the opposite error, because I no longer have a docker environment.

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml so far:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - test

test-backend:
  image: openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd spring
    - ./gradlew test --stacktrace
  tags:
    - docker
```

I was hoping by providing dind as a service that I could somehow have a docker environment, even if I use a different image for my testing stage.
Can someone show me how its done in a proper way?

Edit:
I ended up with this solution, which works perfectly:

```
image: gradle:6.9.4-jdk17-jammy

services:
 - name: docker:dind
   command: ["--tls=false"]

variables:
 DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
 DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
 DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

stages:
  - test

test-api:
  stage: test
  script:
    - gradle test
```

Comment: Check the following blogpost https://www.atomicjar.com/2023/01/running-testcontainers-tests-on-gitlab-ci/

Comment: @EddúMeléndez Thank you, with a bit of tweaking, since I use gradle, it works now.